# How can we change the details which are shown when mouseover on incoming chat request?

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, servicecloud, omnichannel, pre-chat

In Omni-Channel, we want to change the details for the incoming chat request. We want to show the Contact details, Location, etc. instead of what is shown right now. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit these details within the objects compact layout(chat transcript in your case).
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.service_presence_edit_work_item_details_with_compact_layouts.htm&type=5